# Regular expression to check whitespace in the beginning and end of a string

Tags: python, regex

This code supposed not to let strings with whitespaces in the beginning and end. In some reason I have negative result with this code

```
import re
def is_match(pattern, string):
    return True if len(re.compile(pattern).findall(string)) == 1 else False
print(is_match("[^\s]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+[^\s]+", '1'))
```

However, other strings work fine. Can anyone explain why result is negative, or even provide better function (newbie in python).

Comment: Why do you need to identify white space? Is it to remove it?

Comment: No, I need to know is there was whitespace or not. I know - the question a little bit specific...

Comment: @TokenMacGuy: as long as you don't mind creating a temporary copy of `foo`. Probably nicer to check the first and last characters directly.

Answer (score 6):

The regexp you're looking for is `^\s|\s$`:

```
xs = ["no spaces", "  starts", "ends  ", "\t\tboth\n\n", "okay"]

import re
print [x for x in xs if re.search(r'^\s|\s$', x)]

## ['  starts', 'ends  ', '\t\tboth\n\n']
```

`^\s.*?\s$` only matches whitespace on both ends:

```
print [x for x in xs if re.search(r'^\s.*?\s$', x, re.S)]

## ['\t\tboth\n\n']
```

An inverse expression (no starting-ending whitespace) is `^\S.*?\S$`:

```
print [x for x in xs if re.search(r'^\S.*?\S$', x, re.S)]

## ['no spaces', 'okay']
```

Comment: Doesn't the minimum string length have to be 2 to match `r'^\S.*?\S$'`? I would prefer for it to be 1.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way to check for whitespace at the beginning or end of a string doesn't involve regular expressions.

```
if test_string != test_string.strip():
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def is_whiteSpace(string):
    t=' ','\t','\n','\r'
    return string.startswith(t) or string.endswith(t)


print is_whiteSpace(" GO") -> True
print is_whiteSpace("GO") -> False
print is_whiteSpace("GO ") -> True
print is_whiteSpace(" GO ") -> True
```

Comment: That's not very efficient. Why not use `str.startswith()` and `str.endswith()`? Or perhaps check `if mystring[0] in " \t\n\r"`, `if mystring[-1] in " \t\n\r"`?

Answer (score 1):

No fancy regex needed, just use the way more readable:

```
>>> def is_whitespace(s):
    from string import whitespace
    return any((s[0] in whitespace, s[-1] in whitespace))

>>> map(is_whitespace, ("foo", "bar ", " baz", "\tspam\n"))
[False, True, True, True]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to construct a regular expression that detects strings *without* spaces, it's easier to check for strings that DO have spaces and then invert the logic in your code.

Remember that `re.match()` returns `None` (a logical false value) if it *doesn't* find a match, and a `SRE_Match` object (logical true value) if it does find a match. Use that to write something like this:

```
In [24]: spaces_pattern = re.compile ( r"^(\s.+|.+\s)$" )

In [27]: for s in ["Alpha", " Bravo", "Charlie ", " Delta "]:
   ....:     if spaces_pattern.match(s):
   ....:         print ( "%s had whitespace." % s )
   ....:     else:
   ....:         print ( "%s did not have whitespace." % s )
   ....: 
Alpha did not have whitespace.
 Bravo had whitespace.
Charlie  had whitespace.
 Delta  had whitespace.
```

Note the use of the `^$` anchors to force the match over the entire input string.

---

Edit:

This doesn't even need regexp at all - you only need to check the first and last characters:

```
test_strings = ['a', ' b', 'c ', ' d ', 'e f', ' g h', ' i j', ' k l ']
for s in test_strings:
    if s[0] in " \n\r\t":
        print("'%s' started with whitespace." % s)
    elif s[-1] in " \n\r\t":
        print("'%s' ended with whitespace." % s)
    else:
        print("'%s' was whitespace-free." % s)
```

---

Edit 2:

A regex that should work anywhere: `^\S(.*\S)?`. You may need to come up with a local equivalent to `\S` ("anything but whitespace") if your regex dialect doesn't include it.

```
test_strings = ['a', ' b', 'c ', ' d ', 'e f', ' g h', ' i j', ' k l ']
import re

pat = re.compile("^\S(.*\S)?$")

for s in test_strings:
    if pat.match(s):
        print("'%s' had no whitespace." % s)
    else:
        print("'%s' had whitespace." % s)
```

Note that `\S` is the negated form of `\s`, i.e. `\S` means "anything *but* whitespace".

Also note that strings of length 1 are accounted for by making part of the match optional. (You might think to use `\S.*\S`, but this forces a match length of at least 2.)

```
'a' had no whitespace.
' b' had whitespace.
'c ' had whitespace.
' d ' had whitespace.
'e f' had no whitespace.
' g h' had whitespace.
' i j' had whitespace.
' k l ' had whitespace.
```

Comment: And if I want to use it HTML <input pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+"> or in java-script regexp.test(pattern) ?

Comment: You asked for Python. ;) Just a sec while I concoct an appropriate monolithic regex for use in those scenarios...

Comment: Sorry, my bad. But still I want only regular expression :)

Comment: See edited answer. I'm not sure if HTML `<input pattern="...">` fields support the `\S` syntax for negated character classes, but you can come up with an equivalent of `\S` on your own.

Comment: Slight edit: `\S(.+\S)` matches exactly 1 or 3 or more characters... it won't work for two characters. I actually meant `\S(.*\S)`.

Comment: Finally, you probably knew this already, don't *rely* on client-side checks alone to validate your data. There is nothing to stop me submitting custom POST data like `name="   Bobby   "` if my browser doesn't respect the `pattern` property, or if I disable Javascript, or... You need to validate the data you actually receive. Client-side checks are for the user's convenience only.

Answer (score 0):

A variant on ch3ka's suggestion:

```
import string
whitespace = tuple(string.whitespace)

'a '.endswith(whitespace)
## True

'a '.startswith(whitespace)
## False

'a\n'.endswith(whitespace)
## True

'a\t'.endswith(whitespace)
## True
```

I find it easier to remember than the regex stuff (except maybe the bit converting `whitespace` to a tuple).